# T-SQL: Bring Result in a way that results with most searched word in column are shown first

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, search

For example I executed following query:

```
Select * 
From MyTable 
Where Description like '%Leave%'
```

It will return these 3 rows:

```
| ID | Description |
|:---|------------:|
| 1  | What is **Leave**? |     
| 2  | How to avail the **Leave**? where as I am not entitled to **leave**, and **leave** is required. |    
| 3  | Why **Leave** type is not showing in **Leave** type collection. |
```

- ID 1 containing word 'Leave' with count 1
- ID 2 containing word 'Leave' with count 3
- ID 3 containing word 'Leave' with count 2

The problem is that I want to bring the result in a way that results with most searched words in 'Description' column are shown first. As I searched by 'Leave' then the row which is containing word 'Leave' most should come on first.

Is there anyway that I can do it with select query with order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
WITH CTE AS(

SELECT *, LEN([Description]) - LEN(REPLACE([Description],'Leave','')) as CNT
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Description] like '%Leave%'
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

Or without using CTE

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable 
WHERE [Description] like '%Leave%'
ORDER BY LEN([Description]) - LEN(REPLACE([Description],'Leave','')) DESC
```